# Excel IF Date less than a Date not working

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following Excel code:

```
=IF(K4<=31/03/2014,TRUE,FALSE)
```

K4 contains a date:

```
01/01/2014
```

Yes, the code brings back `FALSE`, I have also tried `=IF(K4<="31/03/2014",TRUE,FALSE)` but with the same result.

Any ideas or suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use

`=IF(K4<=DATE(2014,3,31),TRUE,FALSE)`

You are testing an inequality with a `Float` `<=` `String`, which returns `FALSE`. The `DATE(,,)` fx gives you the required `Float` for equality comparison.

Alternatively, `=K4<=DATE(2014,3,31)` is a shorter way of achieving the same.

Comment: For reference, when I placed the date `31/03/2014` in cell `P4` and changed the formula to the following `=IF(K4<P4,TRUE,FALSE)` it also worked.

Answer (score 2):

What `K4<=31/03/2014` evaluates to is:

```
K4 <= (31/03)/2014
```

31/03 gives 10.333... and that divided by 2014 gives 0.005131... which is why it will always evaluate to false (01/01/2014 is equivalent to 41640, i.e. the number of days since '00/01/1900')

I don't know if it's a system thing, but `=IF(K4<="31/03/2014",TRUE,FALSE)` gives me `TRUE`, but then, so does `=IF(K4<="31/03/2013",TRUE,FALSE)`.

A quick and dirty trick would be to multiply the string by 1:

```
=IF(K4<="31/03/2014"*1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

The multiplication tells excel to convert the string to a number, if it is parsable (You can also use any other numerical operation that doesn't change the value itself, such as `+0`).

Note: Excel dates and numbers are the same. Dates are just formatted differently so that a number with a specific format can appear as a date, time, or any other format you can have.

Also, if you really are using this `IF` construct, you are better of simply using the comparator:

```
=K4<="31/03/2014"*1
```

Comment: @pnuts Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by not necessarily visible. The time shouldn't be a problem as far as I see. It's just numeric comparison and decimals are taken into consideration. Wouldn't it be just like using `=K4<=DATE(2014,3,31)`?

Comment: @pnuts Then I would say it should be false. Otherwise, I would use the `<` comparator and one day later... `=K4<"01/04/2014"*1`

Comment: @pnuts Ahh, now I see where you were getting at. Though personally, I will not look for the number of days each time. I'd rather edit in the date if it has to be changed than count the days/convert the date to days each time.

Comment: I see. I hardly ever use the ribbon nowadays. I have put shortcuts I use in the quick access bar and use Alt+N where N is a number to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that excel was not recognizing one of my 2 columns as a date.  (Try changing the date format to 14-Mar-12 to see if this is the case for you)